# How to read data from database and store it in array using linq to sql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I create a database with the data(id) 8,5,1,9,2,3,4,5. Then i want to retrieve the data and store it in an array. Does anyone can help me? I am using C# and linq to SQL.

My code:

```
using(DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext())
{
   var query = from p in db.table1
               select p.id;


   int[] myArray = new int[query];
}
```

Comment: -1 because you could simply have done a 5 minute search. I believe this question shows a significant lack of research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call an extension method `ToArray()`:

```
var array = (from p in db.table1
             select p.id).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 because you answered faster than me. Perhaps you could mention that specifically the extension method is found in `System.Linq`.

Comment: Wow, just that simple. Thanks!